# Existence of common perpendicular line between two affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I would like to prove the following result.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ considered as a Euclidean affine space. Then if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no common point then there exists a line that is intersecting and perpendicular to both of them.

What I have tried is as follows. As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no common point, $\dim \alpha+\dim\beta\leq n$. The case of equality can be treated quite easily since then $\alpha$ is parallel to $\beta$. Consider the case $\dim \alpha+\dim\beta\leq n-1$. Let $V$ and $W$ be directed vector spaces of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then there is a vector space $U$ of dimension $1$ orthogonal to both $V$ and $W$. Of course the line that is perpendicular to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be directed by $U$, but I don't know how to choose $U$ so that the corresponding line intersects both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. What I think is to construct a hyperplane $\gamma$ directed by $V\oplus U$ and containing $\alpha$. Then $\gamma$ should intersect $\beta$ at some point which is on the line we want. However it is not clear to me now.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\alpha=a+V$ and $\beta=b+W$, where $a,b$ are points in $\mathbb R^n$. Since $\dim(V+W)<n$, we can write $\mathbb R^n=(V+W)\oplus (V+W)^\perp$, where $U:=(V+W)^\perp$ is a non-trivial subspace. Consider vector $\vec{ab}= b-a$. Note that $\vec{ab}\notin V+W$, as otherwise $\vec{ab}=\vec v+\vec w$ for some $\vec v\in V$ and $\vec w\in W$, so $a+\vec v=b-\vec w$ is a common point of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Write $\vec{ab}= (\vec v+\vec w)+\vec u$, where $\vec v\in V$, $\vec w\in W$ and $\vec u\in U$, and note $\vec u\neq 0$.

Consider now $a'=a+\vec v\in\alpha$, $b'=b-\vec w\in\beta$, $L=\mathrm{span}(\vec u)$ and affine line $\gamma=a'+L$. $\gamma$ is directed by $L$, i.e. by $\vec u$, so it is normal to $V+W$, i.e. it is normal to both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Clearly, $\gamma$ intersects $\alpha$ in $a'$. Note $b'-a'= (b-a)-(\vec v+\vec w)=\vec{ab}-(\vec v+\vec w)=\vec u$, so $b'=a'+\vec u$ is a common point of $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you very much!